# Gimp: Fill area inside outline

Tags: gimp

Question from the GIMP novice: 
I received a jpg image which shall be used as a logo. Here's a part of it:

[image]

I'd like to have the background transparent, but the letters filled white. I was able to make the whole thing transparent spending some time with GIMP - to demonstrate it, I put it on a yellow background:

[image]

I can also fill the inside of the letters by

1. selecting the outlines of the letters with the magic wand
2. inverting selection
3. de-selecting what I don't need (i.e. the rest of the image)
4. fine adjusting the selection by manually adding/removing pixels and/or groups of pixels to make the whole thing smoother
5. filling the selection with white color

I feel there should be an easier way, but my Google resarch didn't help. Can you? Are there more comfortable tools than GIMP for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the solid JPEG image in GIMP

1. Use the Fuzzy Select tool (aka the Magic Wand) to select inside the letters, while holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> as you click, to add each inside piece to the selection. You may need to adjust the Threshold in the Tool options to get a good selection. In my example below I set the Threshold to 79.
2. In the layers panel create a new transparent layer. Select the new layer and click *Edit > Fill with FG colour* (assuming you already chose white as the FG colour).
3. *Select > None*
4. Click and drag the new filled white layer to the bottom of the layer stack in the Layers panel.
5. Select the top layer. Click *Colours > Colour to Alpha > OK*.  This will make it transparent.

Example shown over a yellow filled background

[image]

As to the second part of your question. Yes there are better solutions for logo creation. The best option would be to use a vector image editor such as Inkscape (also free) to recreate the artwork from scratch. If the logo is simple enough and you know the font, this could be a quicker approach, plus vectors can be scaled without degradation in quality to any size you want.

Comment: Thank you so much! So my mistake was to turn white into transparent before selecting the letters' inside...

Comment: @mic - Possibly, that would add unnecessary complications I think.